# Rails, Heroku and PG Syntax Error for queries with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have been trying to make simple queries with two conditions with `start` and `end` datetimes.

In development mode I don't have any problem and it seems to work well (SQLite)

In production mode however I have the following error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "end"
 LINE 1: ...ions"  WHERE (start >= '2013-01-30T10:12:24Z' AND end >= '20...
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "missions"  WHERE (start >= '2013-01-30T10:12:24Z' AND end >= '2013-01-30T10:12:24Z')):
                                                              ^
     6:                 <li class="mission clearfix">
     1: <h4 class="heading-sep"><%= t(".upcoming_missions")%></h4>
     2: <div class="missions-timeline">
     3:     <ul class="mission-list">
   app/views/users/show.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___1717297229253226868_63256380'
     7:                     <div class="mission-wrap clearfix">
     4:         <% if @upcoming_missions.any? %>

     5:             <% @upcoming_missions.each do |mission| %>
   app/views/users/_mission_timeline.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_users__mission_timeline_html_erb__2786253018340202740_62779040'
```

In my controller I have the following queries:

```
@upcoming_missions = Mission.where("start >= ? AND end >= ?", Time.now, Time.now).order("created_at DESC")

@current_missions = Mission.where("start <= ? AND end >= ?", Time.now, Time.now).order("created_at DESC")

@past_missions = Mission.where("start <= ? AND end <= ?", Time.now, Time.now).order("created_at DESC")
```

I tried other suggestions by including `.utc` in case PG reads time differently than SQLite... but I am not sure where the problem is.

Thank you for your help

Aurelien

Comment: So I think I solved my problem and I am no expert of PostgreSQL. I had to rename the `start` and `end` properties to something more unique such as `start_time` and `end_time`. I guess PostgreSQL reserves words like `end` for its own operations. If someone more competent in PG has a better explanation it would be appreciated by all of us.

Comment: Well done! You're absolutely right - 'end' is a reserved word - see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html Perhaps you could post your own solution as an answer (and accept your own answer) so this will show up as an answered question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to the problem is that the word `end` is a [reserved keyword for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Thank you Micapam for your answers and link.

In my case, my Missions table had datetime columns named `start` and `end`. When running with SQLite in development mode, it was not returning any errors and was sorting my missions the right way. Strangely enough, `end` is also a [reserved keyword in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) but was still letting me run my queries.

In order to solve the problem, I simply renamed my columns in a migration

```
class ChangeStartAndEndFromMission < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :missions do |t|
      t.rename :start, :start_time
      t.rename :end, :end_time
    end
  end
end
```

It is good to check out these reserved keywords to make sure there are no conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to add to Aurelien's answer, but I just wanted to say you could also use `table_name.end` in your condition instead of just `end`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably that 'T' between the date and time that's annoying Postgres. Try using strftime to find a format Postgres likes - something like:

```
Time.now.strftime('%F %T')
```

Which will give you a date/time string something like `2013-01-30 21:58:07`.

Comment: Thank you @micapam for the suggestion. I tried, but the error persists. The `^` has moved to `...sions"  WHERE (start >= '2013-01-30 11:44:57' AND end >= '20...` between the `AND` and `end`.